# How to render dynamic Visuals using D3.js on Google Chrome using a local desktop server?

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js

I have managed to develop D3.js visuals on Mozilla Firefox using a local computer and no server. But if I want to develop it on Google Chrome, only static data (and not dynamic) can be rendered.By Dynamic i mean, having a Dropdown on front end  and a csv at back end to pull the data from.

Comment: If you're accessing data from a file, you should always set up a local web server for development. Different browsers will enforce this in different ways. The D3 docs give examples of a few simple server options: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#using

Answer (score 0):

Run a local server.

From the command line in the directory where index.html resides, run the following python command:

```
python -m SimpleHttpServer
```

This will serve on localhost:8000 by default. If python isn't you style, there are numerous other ways that are easily google-able for you to run a local server.

For more information about how to set up a beginning dev environment, Mike Bostock writes about it [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/block/). He uses http-server from Node for his local server.